# Where to put configuration information for exodus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I am trying to use https://github.com/ThomasAlxDmy/Exodus as a migration tool for rails and mongo using mongo mapper.

I am unclear from the documentation where to place the configuration elements.

What should the configuration file look like?
Where should the configuration of exodus go? config/environment.rb config/application.rb

Comment: I am just starting out doing Rails stuff so I am not sure of the flow.

I can put it in config/appliocation.rb but exodus seems to be unaware of environments. I would like to have it take the configuration of the mongomapper gem. I am configuring this in config/environments/development.rb. However this does not seem to be being picked up by Rake. I changed the Rakefile to require "environment.rb" instead of "application.rb" which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try putting your config in initializers folder?

In your `config/initializers/exodus.rb`

```
require 'exodus'

Exodus.configure do |config|
  # Your config options
end
```

Comment: Will I be able to use the configuration from mongo_mapper to configure exodus? I would rather not like to repeat myself.  

  

    Exodus.configure do |config|
     config.db = MongoMapper.database
    config.connection = MongoMapper.connection